# Random generator matching regexp?

Tags: regex, go

Is there any go package that receives a [regex](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp) as input and returns a random string matching that regex or can you direct me how such a solution can be implemented?

My first thought is to generate random bytes in a loop from /dev/rand and then return one that matches the regex but I think this kind of brute-force would be time consuming until I find one such string matching the regex.

**Use case:**

I'm planning to use this for a web service testing library.

- Some API calls such registering an user account requires unique fields such an email address, phone number etc thus the need of a random input generator based on a patter/regex.
- The random property also helps to safeguard against stale data /false positives (i.e. data that was stored before the current test suite). I guess the generator doesn't need to provide cryptography level randomness but rather something like GUID.

Comment: What kind of string do you think the following regex should deliver? `.*`

Comment: Do you want a *random* string or an arbitrary string? For example,  if you returned the same thing every time for a given regex, would that work?

Comment: since you'd have to have very limited regexes to constrain the output within reason, why not just define the format of the random characters you want in the first place?

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling that this might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm curious to know what this would be used for...

Comment: @merlin2011 I guess random would be better than arbitrary because there might be a conflict using the same string(though it's not always the case). I've updated the question with further details about the use case.

Comment: @Aedolon I've updated the question with the use case details.

Comment: cc @hek2mgl: I've updated the question with the use case details. I guess some sensible default limits/flags could be put in place but the generator should try to produce a small/ efficient output.

Comment: The only solution i see is to convert a regex to a finite automata (which is  done in any regex library) and find a path from the initial state to any final state. That path will be a string that matches the regex.

Comment: [**Xeger**](https://github.com/sethgrid/xeger). It does not work in Go yet, but the [Python version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xeger) is working.

Comment: Xeger looks great but unfortunately as you said it's not working in Go. I can't use Python  b/c I can't run os/exec

Comment: I'm  not convinced that what you're asking for is actually a good solution for your use case. Generating all kinds of random strings is easy, but regexps aren't great for *strict* matching of email addresses and phone numbers anyway, so I don't see why those random strings would need to be particularly strictly formatted either. (Writing a regexp that can validate an email address is *incredibly* complicated...)

Comment: @Aedolon, what's the alternative? Writing a "custom" generator for each kind of pattern I need? (e.g. phone number generator, string 10 chars, string 1 char etc). And what if the test case needs to be declarative?(i.e. in a json file). I believe regex are the only way to express patterns declaratively, at least that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Theu, I'd probably write a couple of custom generators (email, phone) and some generic "give me a string of length N composed of [xyz] characters" functions. Do you really need a fake phone number that's formatted in some *exact* manner? Do you know how many ways to represent a valid phone number there are in the world?

Comment: ` "give me a string of length N composed of [xyz] characters"` sounds like a lightweight regex... why not supporting the full regex (if such a package would be available) so that I can use it for both on simple string generation and  less common cases (i.e. an email address)? Complex input types such  email and phone numbers are not that common but still they have a regex . I don't see much value reinventing the regex in a simpler form. If you need simple strings then you can use simple regex.  Concerning the phone number example there might be many formats but I don't need to test them all.

Comment: Also, if you're doing this for testing it might not be that helpful, since you're only generating input that you know will pass the regex. You're not going to get a full range of possible emails unless your email regex truly going to validate all emails. This is why you use a parser and not a regex for email: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html (sorry, that was probably too far OT)

Comment: @JimB the testing framework/tool I'm developing is meant to mainly test the logic of the application not really the validation rules. Randomness it's a feature to address the conflicting and stale data. For rule validations I think a specialized tool is required, perhaps something like/based on Go Fuzz github.com/dvyukov/go-fuzz ). Shortly said the random input generator would answer this demand: `Give me a valid [phone number/email etc] that was not used before!` so that I can use it to register a fake/test user. The input generated must be random (like GUID) to avoid a db conn.

Answer (score 7):

[Reggen](https://github.com/lucasjones/reggen) is a library that I've written that can generate strings from regular expressions. It can be used to generate the email addresses/phone numbers you need, and anything else specified with a regular expression.

In general the more specific the provided regular expressions are, the better results it gives. For example, the regex `.*@.*\..*` might generate something like `F$-^@A"%mk.^uv`, but `[a-z]+@[a-z]+\.(com|net|org)` should result in something more readable like `bfeujqp@qtpqby.com`

Generating an email address with the library:

```
import "github.com/lucasjones/reggen"

func main() {
    str, err := reggen.Generate("^[a-z]{5,10}@[a-z]{5,10}\\.(com|net|org)$", 10)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Typical output:

```
tpbry@sfmxet.net
```